# If $f(x), \phi(x)$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$, how can I show that $\int_a^b f(x)\phi(x) dx = 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose that $f(x), \phi(x)$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$ where $\phi(x)$ has the following property
$$
\int_a^b x^k \phi(x) dx = 0
$$
for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $\int_a^b f(x)\phi(x) dx = 0$.

Certainly, $\int_a^b x^k \phi(x) dx = 0$ if $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x$. However, for a nonzero function $\phi(x)$, if $\int_a^b x^k \phi(x) dx = 0$, then the antiderivative of $x^k \phi(x) = 0$ over $[a,b]$. This is where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to calculate the antiderivative or if I need to do that in order to extrapolate the integral for all continuous functions, $f(x)$. Any suggestions/hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Continuous functions on compact intervals can be approximated by polynomials to within arbitrary precision

Comment: Incidentally here we will also have $\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Weierstrass theorem tells that $f(x)$ can be approximated by a polynomial.